# Embedded Jetty application

Tags: java, jetty

I a newbie in Jetty. I have created an application in which I embed the jetty web container. When I run the the application from eclipse it runs perfectly without any issues. However when I export the project with all the required libraries and run it from command line I cannot access the index.jsp web page like I used to in eclispe. This is the file that run the jetty web container.

```
public class JettyServer {

// The folder containing all the .jsp files
private final static String WEB_ROOT = "src/WebContent";

// Instance of the Jetty server
private final static Server SRV = new Server();

// Context Path
private final static String CONTEXT_PATH = "/smpp";

// Logging 
private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JettyServer.class);

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws ConfigurationException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
    logger.info("Initializing Web Server......");

    // Servlet Context
    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    // Set the security constraints
    context.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
    context.setResourceBase(WEB_ROOT);

    context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");
    context.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");

    String [] welcomeFiles = {"index.jsp"};
    context.setWelcomeFiles(welcomeFiles);
    // Set the .jsp servlet handlers
    final ServletHolder jsp = context.addServlet(JspServlet.class, "*.jsp");
    jsp.setInitParameter("classpath", context.getClassPath());

    // Session Manager
    SessionHandler sh = new SessionHandler();       
    context.setSessionHandler(sh);

    /* Http Request Handlers */
    context.addServlet(HttpRequestProcessor.class, "/HttpHandler");

    // Server configuration setup
    // Connector setup
    //  We explicitly use the SocketConnector because the SelectChannelConnector locks files
    Connector connector = new SocketConnector();
    connector.setHost("localhost");
    connector.setPort(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("jetty.port", new PropertiesConfiguration("smpp-config.properties").getString("http_port").trim())));
    connector.setMaxIdleTime(60000);

    JettyServer.SRV.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
    JettyServer.SRV.setHandler(context);
    JettyServer.SRV.setAttribute("org.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize", 0);
    JettyServer.SRV.setGracefulShutdown(5000);
    JettyServer.SRV.setStopAtShutdown(true);

    logger.info("Starting Jetty Web Container....");
    try{
        JettyServer.SRV.start();
    } 
    catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Jetty Web Container failed to start [CAUSE : " + ex.getMessage() + "]");
        return;
    }


    logger.info("Jetty Web Container running....");
    while(true){
        try{
            JettyServer.SRV.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException iex){
            logger.error("Jetty Web Container interrupted [CAUSE : " + iex.getMessage() + "]");
        }
    }       
}   
}
```

code formatted properly

Comment: @zdesam Thank you. Please can you assist me?

Comment: provide any error / exception if encoutered at server-side

Comment: @TechExchange When I run the command java -jar <myjar_file> this the output:  2013-01-28/10:36:01.212  INFO: Http.JettyServer - Initializing Web Server......
2013-01-28/10:36:01.558  INFO: Http.JettyServer - Starting Jetty Web Container....
2013-01-28/10:36:01.561  INFO: server.Server - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2013-01-28/10:36:01.761  INFO: server.AbstractConnector - Started SocketConnector@localhost:8080
2013-01-28/10:36:01.767  INFO: Http.JettyServer - Jetty Web Container running.... . When I try accessing the page it seems is going to load the page but nothing comes.

Comment: @TechExchange However from within eclipse it works.

Comment: 2013-01-28/10:48:36.020 DEBUG: server.session - session=null
2013-01-28/10:48:36.024 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - servlet /smpp|/|null -> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-1
2013-01-28/10:48:36.028 DEBUG: servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
2013-01-28/10:48:36.032 DEBUG: servlet.DefaultServlet - Resource /=null
2013-01-28/10:48:36.035 DEBUG: servlet.DefaultServlet - uri=/smpp/ resource=null
2013-01-28/10:48:36.039 DEBUG: server.Server - RESPONSE /smpp/  404 handled=true

Comment: What I observe is that eclipse prepend the app root folder to the webroot whilst in the jar file when I run the app root folder is not prepend to the webroot. Any help???????? Guys please help

Comment: what is the complete url you are trying ?

Comment: @TechExchange  localhost:8080/smpp. It seems that it doesn't load the src/WebContent because when I run it from the CLI I can see that <jar_location>/src/WebContent instead of <project_folder>/src/WebContent.

Comment: See the solution I found for my question: [What is correct URL to specify ResourceBase of JAR “resources/webapp” folder for embedded Jetty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154708/what-is-correct-url-to-specify-resourcebase-of-jar-resources-webapp-folder-for?noredirect=1#comment39167596_25154708).  That will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Your use of relative paths in the `context.setResourceBase("src/WebContent");` will cause you problems.

Use a full, and absolute, URI reference with `context.setResourceBase(String)`.

Note that you can use the following URI schemes: `file`, `ftp`, `jar`, and even `http`

Comment: Please can you tell how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
```

Can you use this ?

```
WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
```

and rest of the code as example :

```
String webappDirLocation = "src/Webcontent/";

Server server = new Server(8080);


root.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
root.setDescriptor(webappDirLocation + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
root.setResourceBase(webappDirLocation);

root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

server.setHandler(root);
```

Comment: Hello TechExchange I did what yo have asked me but I am still not able to load the jsp page. I created the web.xml file and setup the various servlet in it.