# What is correct URL to specify ResourceBase of JAR "resources/webapp" folder for embedded Jetty?

Tags: java, maven, url, jar, jetty-9

We want a simple embedded Jetty servelet with the web resources inside a JAR-file's resources folder.  We have some properties files in the JAR and load them using a resources path.  We want to specify the Jetty Resource Base to be:

- resources/**webapp**
- set:  resource_handler.**setResourceBase**( "webapp" )

  - Via the correct URL to point to that resource in the [JAR file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/JarURLConnection.html).

Folder in the JAR file.  This is a bare bones JAR file (not WAR, no frameworks, without Spring, as vanilla *as we may*).  Initial tests continue to throw exceptions for something like the following strings:

```
webPath = "jar:file:!/webapp";     //.... runs the Jetty server 
 ... 
resource_handler.setResourceBase( webPath );
```

Although the server seems to run, the result fails to find my index.html. (***Update***:) This example is just taking from the Jetty "[Embedded File Server](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-file-server)" example.  In this case, the requirement is for the Jetty **Resource Base** to map to the JAR file (full-URL):

- "jar:file:!/webapp/index.html",

as follows:

- resource_handler.setResourceBase("**jar:file:!/webapp**");

Instead of the example given:

- resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

And we want this to map the browser URL as:

- localhost:8080/index.html

  - ... giving ...
- jar:file:!/webapp/index.html

For contrast the JAR path that work for config files below.  The question: what should [the URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/JarURLConnection.html) be so Jetty resource base can serve-up my Index.html file?

- resources/

  - config/

    - display.properties

file is: "/config/display.properties" and this works in the same project code using a load resources operation. The layout is like this:

```
 app.jar
   +----- com /
   |        +--- ( classes ... )
   |
   +----- config /
   |        |
   |        +--- display.properties
   |
   +----- webapp /
            |
            +--- index.html
```

To give the general idea.

**similar** questions:

- [Starting up embedded jetty server for a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672684/starting-up-embedded-jetty-server-for-a-jar-file)

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/index.html`? When jar runs.

Comment: Sorry, no.  The question is about the appropriate JAR file URL to bind to Jetty's **ResourceBase**.  Even with, "jar:file:!/webapp", the embedded server does NOT find the: "http://localhost:8080/index.html" resource.  Reason: "**Not Found**"

Comment: Sorry too. `resource_handler.setResourceBase(this.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/webapp").toExternalForm());` See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty

Comment: Thank you, yes we used that, this gives a **null** because there is no file-path to: "/webapp".  The correct Java URL for the JAR is as explained in: [JarUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/JarURLConnection.html).  That is: "_jar:file:!/webapp_".  The challenge is that this Resource Base can't resolve the browser input-URL: "localhost:8080/index.html" to map to: "**jar:file:!/webapp/index.html**" in the [JAR file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/JarURLConnection.html)

Comment: That looks like default functionality. Did you try a demo sample project, before checking where your project differs? Sorry no time now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a working solution - Work-around that I'm posting in the hope that this approach will inspire correct method.  I still believe there ought to be a way to specify a folder inside the JAR, relative to the JAR.

Anyway this method works.  I used it to server static web content from within the JAR.  Essentially I have Java resolve the absolute path to the running JAR resource and pass that path name to Jetty.  When I do that Jetty displays my "helloWorld.html", welcome file.

```
    String  baseStr  = "/webapp";  //... contains: helloWorld.html, login.html, etc. and folder: other/xxx.html
    URL     baseUrl  = SplitFileServerRunner.class.getResource( baseStr ); 
    String  basePath = baseUrl.toExternalForm();

      .... 
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);      //... just for testing
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "helloWorld.html" });
    resource_handler.setResourceBase( basePath );
    LOG.info("serving: " + resource_handler.getBaseResource());
```

In the welcome file, I have put specific text to identify the file's origin (in the resources folder).  In the browser:

- localhost:8080

Serves the helloWorld.html file.

- localhost:8080/other

Shows a directory listing of the **jar:/webapp/other/** directory inside the JAR file.  This relies on **not** changing the JAR while the server is running.

On Linux if someone **cp**-s a new jarfile on-top of the running JAR, Jetty gives:

```
 HTTP ERROR: 500

 Problem accessing /. Reason:

        java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And you can't access pages any more.  That was unexpected (evidently the JAR is kept open).   The good news is that if you **mv**-s the jarfile:

- mv fileserver.jar  fileserverXX.jar

Jetty happily continues serving from the (renamed) fileserverXX.jar content.  I can be happy with that.  However I'd still like to know the equivalent relative path to match the absolute file name.

Comment: I had hoped someone would come along with an alternative solution by now (6 months later).   Let's call it answered and move along.  I believe this is a relevant requirement for the new Java (9??) packaging container -- But the requirement would need to be more general purpose.

Comment: ... and this method still works in 2022 :)

Answer (score 0):

Some methods changed since the original answer so the following works the same way but with Jetty's version: 9.4.12.v20180830:

```
ServletContextHandler webappContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);  
URL webRootLocation = JettyStart.class.getResource("/webapp/index.html");  
URI webRootUri = URI.create(webRootLocation.toURI().toASCIIString().replaceFirst("/index.html$", "/"));  
webappContext.setContextPath("/");
webappContext.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
webappContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
```

Comment: I see, yes.  Actually for full disclosure a method that uses the `...getResource("/webapp/index.html")` method _ought_ to more correctly be considering the Class Loader that relates to the required resource URI.  Packages like Jetty often use their own class loader(s).